# Using rails engine path helpers in a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have mounted an engine in my rails app. In a controller, I can access the engine path helpers by prefixing the path with the name of the engine e.g. `myengine.articles_path`.  I want to access these helpers in a service class. Normally I would include the url_helpers i.e.

```
class SomeService
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

end
```

This allows me to access the helpers in my main app, e.g. `root_path`, but if I try `myengine.articles_path` I get

```
undefined local variable or method `myengine'
```

How do I access the engine path helpers in a service class or some module like that?

Answer (score 7):

It has to be put into `class << self`

```
class SomeService
  class << self
   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```